# Ordering a queryset while ignoring a value

Tags: python, django

I have a field `hotrank`, It saves hot music (1,2,3,4...10)
But if the music didn't make it in top 10, I will save 0.
And I have another field called `releaseday` which saves the release day of the music

And now I want to query :

```
 Music.objects.filter(releaseday__lte=today).order_by('hotrank','-releaseday')
```

But here is a problem,the order_by of hotrank is start by 0 ,but 0 is not the top music
how can I let order_by start from `hotrank=1`? Is there any method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the queryset's `extra()` method with SQL `CASE` expression:

```
Music.objects.filter(releaseday__lte=today) \
             .extra({'vrank': 'CASE WHEN hotrank=0 THEN 11 ELSE hotrank END'}) \
             .order_by('vrank','-releaseday')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can results with hotrank=0 from the query results, like this:

```
Music.objects.filter(releaseday__lte=today).exclude(hotrank=0).order_by(
                     '-hotrank','-releaseday')
```

If you want to add the results of those with hotrank=0 right after the ordered results you can do it this way:

```
released_music = Music.objects.filter(releaseday__lte=today).order_by('-hotrank',
                                                                      '-releaseday')
result = released_music.exclude(hotrank=0) | released_music.filter(hotrank=0)
```

Comment: but I still need  the music with ````hotrank=0````  although it's not in top10

Comment: Is it right if we append after these query results those guys with hotrank=0? So the results will be: hotrank=1...10 and then those with hotrank=0

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to achieve this through Django queries. I also discourage you to use any database specific queries. You can pull all your objects from database and sort them the way you want in Python:

```
music_list = Music.objects.filter(releaseday__lte=today).all()
sorted_music = sorted(music_list, key=lambda x: x.hotrank if x.hotrank > 0 else 11)
```

Comment: ````'list' object has no attribute '_clone'```` I got this error,could you give me some direction ?

Comment: @user2492364 This means your using sorted_music which is a list where a queryset is expected. How are you using sorted_music?